# How do i select with multiple cases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Apologies in advance for the messy presentation. ( | act as separator)

Below are my DataSet, Desired Output (With derived Desired_Contradiction from the rules)

Your help is needed in:- 
1.Coming up with Desire_Final_Contradiction field. (I tried the following script but it didn't work)

```
select
  ID,
  'Final_Contradiction' = CASE WHEN (
    (B.[DataEntry] in (1,2) and B.[Contradiction] = 1) or
    (B.[DataEntry] in (2,3) and B.[Contradiction] = 1))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END
from Test
```

**Sample_Dataset**

```
create table Sample (
  Id int,
  VoterId int,
  DataEntry int,
  Contradiction int)

insert into Sample(Id, VoterId, DataEntry, Contradiction)
values
  (14389, 162178, 1, 1),
  (14389, 161966, 2, 1),
  (212, 379220, 1, 0),
  (212, 379213, 2, 0),
  (14482, 19942, 1, 1),
  (14482, 37541, 2, 1),
  (14621, 11150, 1, 0),
  (14621, 11149, 2, 1),
  (14621, 35449, 3, 1),
  (14741, 26904, 1, 1),
  (14741, 46558, 2, 1),
  (14741, 37923, 3, 1)
```

**Desired output**

```
ID     | VoterId | DataEntry | Desired_Contradiction
14389  | 161966  | 2         | 1
212    | 379213  | 2         | 0
14482  | 37541   | 2         | 1
14621  | 11149   | 2         | 1
14741  | 46558   | 2         | 1
```

Rules:-

1. Logic for the Desired_Contradiction field in the Desired Output
   For 2 Data Entries The desired_contradiction will be 1 when (the below logic is meet) else  0

```
Data_Entry | Contradiction  
1          | 1   
2          | 1
```

For 3 Data Entries The_final_contradiction will be 1 when (the below logic is meet) else 0

```
Data_Entry | Contradiction
1          | 0 or 1
2          | 1   
3          | 1
```

2. VoterId in the Desired output will be the voterID from DataEntry=2

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you very Much.

Comment: You really need to better format your question, I doubt you might get any answer like that.

Comment: @PaulKaram: don't really know how to format my question as i am unable to insert pic. any heads up?

Comment: It's not preferred to just post a picture also. You better check that [help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and get yourself familiar with it.

Comment: [Forum Etiquette: how to post sample data for a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Thanks @PaulKaram

Comment: Some good information and links to formatting tools here: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me with the format and trying to improve the readability but then i would really appreciate if someone could help me out with getting the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: Your desired contradiction logic doesn't apply to ID 14741. This record has three 1s, your desired output is 1, but your logic says first data entry should be 0 to get 1 as result.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci: thank you for the heads up. My original logic was replaced and the 0 or 1 value for Data_Entry = 1 in the second rule was replaced when i accepted the multiple reviews on the structure of my question. I have re-edit it. Thank you.

Comment: @Joey edited my response for the new edit. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution, just sharing in case someone might be looking at the same query:-

```
select ID
,CASE WHEN VOTERID2 is not null then VOTERID2 ELSE VOTERID END VOTERID -- always check if VOTERID2 populated then take VOTERID2 else VOTERID. VOTERID3 is not used
,CASE   WHEN DATAENTRY2 is not null then DATAENTRY2 else DATAENTRY END DATAENTRY -- always check if DATAENTRY2 is not null then take DATAENTRY2 else use DATAENTRY. DATAENTRY3 is not used
,CASE   WHEN CONTRADICTION =1 and CONTRADICTION2 = 1 AND CONTRADICTION3 is null then '1'
        WHEN CONTRADICTION in (0,1) and CONTRADICTION2 = 1 AND CONTRADICTION3 = 1 then '1'
        ELSE '0'
        END CONTRADICTION
from (
       Select ID,VOTERID,DATAENTRY,CONTRADICTION
             ,LEAD (VOTERID,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS VOTERID2
             ,LEAD (DATAENTRY,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS DATAENTRY2
             ,LEAD (CONTRADICTION,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS CONTRADICTION2
             ,LEAD (VOTERID,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS VOTERID3 
             ,LEAD (DATAENTRY,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS DATAENTRY3
             ,LEAD (CONTRADICTION,2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS CONTRADICTION3
       from sample
      ) SAMPLE_COMBINE 
        Where DATAENTRY = 1
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest solution, but it might give you a head start:

```
;WITH DataEntry2VoterID AS
(
    SELECT
        S.ID,
        S.VoterId
    FROM
        Sample AS S
    WHERE
        S.DataEntry = 2
)
SELECT
    S.Id,
    V.VoterId,
    ContradictionThingy = CASE
        WHEN 
            COUNT(1) = 2 AND SUM(S.Contradiction) = 2 THEN 1
        WHEN 
            COUNT(1) = 3 AND SUM(CASE 
                WHEN S.DataEntry IN (2,3) AND S.Contradiction = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE -999 END) = 2 THEN 1
        ELSE 
            0 END
FROM
    Sample AS S
    LEFT JOIN DataEntry2VoterID AS V ON S.Id = V.Id
GROUP BY
    S.Id,
    V.VoterId
```

Comment: Hi @Ezequiel Lopez: Thank you for trying but then the code only works when the contradiction tingy is both 1. I think can't use in as in is for when the row is mutually exclusive with each other. It doesn't consider both the rows as and. No worries i found out the solution and will share it.